# I accidentally deleted the venv folder in PyCharm and now have a problem with running it

Tags: python, pycharm

I didn't mean to do that and now have a problem with running files. It displays this error:

```
> Error running 'server': Cannot run program
> "C:\Users\35568\PycharmProjects\chatapp\venv\Scripts\python.exe" (in
> directory "C:\Users\35568\PycharmProjects\chatapp\Server"):
> CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I looked into the Scripts file, but don't really know what to do, as I am practically a beginner. I also looked the problem up online and found something about Docker, but when I looked into the settings of my IDE, I didn't find it. What do I do now?

Comment: Just create another virtualenv. Look up about it online. If you don't have a `requirements.txt`, I'm afraid you'll have to remember and install each of the packages you had installed in the env you deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted your venv, just open `cmd` in project directory and run `python -m venv venv` - where second `venv` is the name of virtual enviroment.

Comment: i actually deleted it inside the IDE. idk where the file went. i tried what you just said, but it didn't seem to work. i still get the error message. when i try to change the interpreter it gives an error saying: invalid python SDK. what does this mean?

Comment: It means that PyCharm couldn't find python virtual enviroment. In IDE you need to change venv. I used PyCharm years ago but I believe that this option is in top right corner. If this wouldn't help, just create new project and copy your code.